# Event for bulk updating product status

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, soap

I am trying to find event when admin mass update product status from productgrid.

[image]

I have found `catalog_product_status_update` but this not seem to dispatch on bulk update of status.

I need event for observer to call extern webservice when product status change.

When i update single product from i have it working with `catalog_product_save_after`.

Any suggestions to help me archieve what i want?

This is what i have so far.

Config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <DM_Microcom>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </DM_Microcom>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <microcom>
                <class>DM_Microcom_Helper</class>
            </microcom>
            <admin>
                <rewrite>
                    <data>DM_Microcom_Helper_Admin_Data</data>
                </rewrite>
            </admin>
        </helpers>
        <models>
            <microcom>
                <class>DM_Microcom_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>microcom_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </microcom>
        </models>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <catalog_product_save_after_handler>
                        <type>singleton</type> 
                        <class>microcom/observer</class>
                        <method>SetWebVare</method>
                    </catalog_product_save_after_handler>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_save_after>
            <catalog_product_status_update> 
                <observers>
                    <catalog_product_status_update_handler>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>microcom/observer</class>
                        <method>SetWebVare</method>
                    </catalog_product_status_update_handler>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_status_update>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

Observer

```
<?php
class DM_Microcom_Model_Observer{

            public function SetWebVare(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
            {
                $user = "USERNAMEHERE";
                $pass = "PASSHERE";
                $product = $observer->getProduct();
                $sku = $product->getSku();
                $newStatus = $product->getStatus();
                $oldStatus = $product->getOrigData('status');
                $status = ($newStatus == 2 ? 0 : 1); 

                if ($newStatus != $oldStatus) {

                    $params = array(              
                        'Brugernavn' => $user, 
                        'Adgangskode' => $pass,
                        'VNr' => $sku,


                'Status' => $status           
                );  

                Mage::log('SetWebVare sku:' . $sku . '. Status: ' . $status, null, 'microcom.log');
                $soapclient = new SoapClient('http://example.com/webservices?wsdl');
                $response = $soapclient->V01_SetWEBVare($params);                   
            }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

**For Magento >= 1.9.2.0:**

The event you are looking for is `catalog_controller_product_mass_status`, it is dispatched under the `massStatusAction` of `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php`

However this event only provides the ids of the products that are mass updated, which you can retrieve this way in your observer:

```
$productsIds = $observer->getEvent()->getProductIds();
```

**For Magento >= 1.6.0.0-beta1:**

On top of that you can also observe one of the following events (depending on your needs):

- `catalog_product_attribute_update_before` which is dispatched in the `updateAttributes` method of the `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Action.php`
- `catalog_product_attribute_update_after` which is dispatched in the same location as the previous one

***BEWARE***: thore events are not only triggered by the mass status action, they are also triggered by other Magento functionalities, use with care.

As the `massStatusAction` method calls the following code, those two events will be dispatched:

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')
            ->updateAttributes($productIds, array('status' => $status), $storeId);
```

You can use two two events in your observer this way:

For the first event:

```
// Get the attribute data
$attributesData = $observer->getEvent()->getAttributesData();
// Get the product ids
$productIds = $observer->getEvent()->getProductIds();
// Get the store id
$storeId = $observer->getEvent()->getStoreId();
```

For the second one you can only do:

```
// Get the product ids
$productIds = $observer->getEvent()->getProductIds();
```

**For Magento < 1.6.0.0-beta1:**

I guess the last solution here is to observer one the following event: `controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_catalog_product_massStatus`

You can use it in your observer this way:

```
// Get the request
$request = $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction()->getRequest();
// Get the product ids
$productIds = $request->getParam('product');
// Get the store id
$storeId = (int)$request->getParam('store',0);
// Get the status applied
$status = $request->getParam('status');
```

Comment: Just did a test and event not being dispatched with catalog_controller_product_mass_status :(

Comment: @puntable which version of Magento are you using ?

Comment: Old one Magento ver. 1.5.1.0

Comment: @puntable I've edited my answer

Comment: I am getting inconsistent results with controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_catalog_product_massStatus. It does not dispatch every time.

Comment: @puntable what do you mean by "not every time" ? This is an event that's automatically dispatched everytime the `massStatus` method is called, there's no way it can be skipped.

Answer (score 1):

You need to rewrite **Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController**

```
 public function massStatusAction()
    {
        $productIds = (array)$this->getRequest()->getParam('product');
        $storeId    = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('store', 0);
        $status     = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('status');

        try {
            $this->_validateMassStatus($productIds, $status);
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')
                ->updateAttributes($productIds, array('status' => $status), $storeId);

            $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                $this->__('Total of %d record(s) have been updated.', count($productIds))
            );
        }
        catch (Mage_Core_Model_Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()
                ->addException($e, $this->__('An error occurred while updating the product(s) status.'));
        }

      //dispatch event
      $data = array( 'somedata' => 'your-data', 'layout' => $this->getLayout());
      Mage::dispatchEvent('custom_event_name', $data);

        $this->_redirect('*/*/', array('store'=> $storeId));
    }
```

observer code as below:

```
<custom_event_name> 
       <observers>
                <catalog_product_status_update_handler>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>microcom/observer</class>
                    <method>SetWebVare</method>
                </catalog_product_status_update_handler>
        </observers>
</custom_event_name>
```